# i am getting an error in eclipse - An error occurred while instantiating class : 'void org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.put(java.lang.Object)'

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi, data-driven-tests

Here is my code i am using

```
package testCases;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.testng.Reporter;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.*;

import base.TestBase;

public class StudentRegistrationForm extends TestBase {

    @Test(dataProvider="getData")
    public void addStudent(String fname, String email, String CurrentAddress,String PermAddress) {
        
        driver.get(confg.getProperty("url2"));
        log.debug("Navigated to : " + confg.getProperty("url2"));
        
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(or.getProperty("fullname"))).sendKeys(fname);
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(or.getProperty("email"))).sendKeys(email);
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(or.getProperty("currentAddress"))).sendKeys(CurrentAddress);
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(or.getProperty("permAddress"))).sendKeys(PermAddress);
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(or.getProperty("submit"))).click();
        log.debug("Completed Test 2 - Student Registration Form");
        Reporter.log("Completed Test 2 - Student Registration Form");
    }
    
    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] getData(){
        
        String SheetName = "sheet1";
        
        int rows = excel.getRowCount(SheetName);
        int cols = excel.getColumnCount(SheetName);
        
        Object[][] data = new Object[rows-1][cols];
        
        for(int RowNum = 2; RowNum < rows; RowNum++) {
            for(int colNum = 0; colNum < cols; colNum++) {
                data[RowNum-2][colNum] = excel.getCellData(SheetName, colNum, RowNum);
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

Also here is the excel reader. I don't know why I am getting an error attached in the picture:

```
package utilities;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;

import org.apache.poi.common.usermodel.HyperlinkType;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.list.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFDateUtil;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FillPatternType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.IndexedColors;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCreationHelper;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFont;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFHyperlink;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExcelReader {
    
    public String path;
    public FileInputStream fis =null;
    public FileOutputStream fileOut = null;
    
    private XSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
    private XSSFSheet sheet = null;
    private XSSFRow row = null;
    private XSSFCell cell = null;
    
    public ExcelReader(String Path) {
        
        this.path = Path;
        
        try {
            
            fis = new FileInputStream(Path);
            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
            sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            fis.close();
        
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public int getRowCount(String Sheetname) {
        
        int sheetIndex  = workbook.getSheetIndex(Sheetname);
        
        if(sheetIndex ==-1)
             return 0;
        else {
            sheet =  workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            int num = sheet.getLastRowNum();
            return num;
        }
        
    }
    
    public String getCellData(String sheetname, String colName, int rowNum) {
    
        try {
            
            if (rowNum <= 0)
                 return "";
            int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetname);
            int col_num = -1;
            if(index == -1)
                return "";
            sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);
            row = sheet.getRow(0);
            for(int i =0;i < row.getLastCellNum(); i++) {
                
                System.out.println(row.getCell(i).getStringCellValue().trim());
                if(row.getCell(i).getStringCellValue().trim().equals(colName.trim()))
                    col_num = i;
            }
            
            if(col_num == -1)
                return "";
            sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);
            row = sheet.getRow(rowNum-1);
            if(row == null)
                 return "";
            cell = row.getCell(col_num);
            
            if(cell==null)
                return "";
            if(cell.getCellType()==CellType.STRING)
                  return cell.getStringCellValue();
            else if(cell.getCellType()==CellType.NUMERIC || cell.getCellType()==CellType.FORMULA ){
                  
                  String cellText  = String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                  if (HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                       
                      double d = cell.getNumericCellValue();

                      Calendar cal =Calendar.getInstance();
                      cal.setTime(HSSFDateUtil.getJavaDate(d));
                        cellText =
                         (String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR))).substring(2);
                       cellText = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" +
                                  cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1 + "/" + 
                                  cellText;
                             

                     }

                  
                  
                  return cellText;
              }else if(cell.getCellType()==CellType.BLANK)
                  return ""; 
              else 
                  return String.valueOf(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "row "+rowNum+" or column "+colName +" does not exist in xls";
        }
    }
            


    // returns the data from a cell
    public String getCellData(String sheetName,int colNum,int rowNum){
        try{
            if(rowNum <=0)
                return "";
        
        int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName);

        if(index==-1)
            return "";
        
    
        sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);
        row = sheet.getRow(rowNum-1);
        if(row==null)
            return "";
        cell = row.getCell(colNum);
        if(cell==null)
            return "";
        
      if(cell.getCellType()==CellType.STRING)
          return cell.getStringCellValue();
      else if(cell.getCellType()==CellType.NUMERIC || cell.getCellType()==CellType.FORMULA ){
          
          String cellText  = String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());
          if (HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
               // format in form of M/D/YY
              double d = cell.getNumericCellValue();

              Calendar cal =Calendar.getInstance();
              cal.setTime(HSSFDateUtil.getJavaDate(d));
                cellText =
                 (String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR))).substring(2);
               cellText = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1 + "/" +
                          cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" +
                          cellText;
               
             

             }

          
          
          return cellText;
      }else if(cell.getCellType()==CellType.BLANK)
          return "";
      else 
          return String.valueOf(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "row "+rowNum+" or column "+colNum +" does not exist  in xls";
        }
    }
    
    
    
    
    // returns true if data is set successfully else false
    public boolean setCellData(String sheetName,String colName,int rowNum, String data){
        try{
        fis = new FileInputStream(path); 
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

        if(rowNum<=0)
            return false;
        
        int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName);
        int colNum=-1;
        if(index==-1)
            return false;
        
        
        sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);
        

        row=sheet.getRow(0);
        for(int i=0;i<row.getLastCellNum();i++){
            //System.out.println(row.getCell(i).getStringCellValue().trim());
            if(row.getCell(i).getStringCellValue().trim().equals(colName))
                colNum=i;
        }
        if(colNum==-1)
            return false;

        sheet.autoSizeColumn(colNum); 
        row = sheet.getRow(rowNum-1);
        if (row == null)
            row = sheet.createRow(rowNum-1);
        
        cell = row.getCell(colNum); 
        if (cell == null)
            cell = row.createCell(colNum);

        
        cell.setCellValue(data);

        fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path);

        workbook.write(fileOut);

        fileOut.close();    

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    
    
    
    // returns true if data is set successfully else false
    public boolean setCellData(String sheetName,String colName,int rowNum, String data,String url){
        
        try{
        fis = new FileInputStream(path); 
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

        if(rowNum<=0)
            return false;
        
        int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName);
        int colNum=-1;
        if(index==-1)
            return false;
        
        
        sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);
        
        row=sheet.getRow(0);
        for(int i=0;i<row.getLastCellNum();i++){
            
            if(row.getCell(i).getStringCellValue().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(colName))
                colNum=i;
        }
        
        if(colNum==-1)
            return false;
        sheet.autoSizeColumn(colNum); 
        row = sheet.getRow(rowNum-1);
        if (row == null)
            row = sheet.createRow(rowNum-1);
        
        cell = row.getCell(colNum); 
        if (cell == null)
            cell = row.createCell(colNum);
            
        cell.setCellValue(data);
        XSSFCreationHelper createHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();

        //cell style for hyperlinks
        
        CellStyle hlink_style = workbook.createCellStyle();
        XSSFFont hlink_font = workbook.createFont();
        hlink_font.setUnderline(XSSFFont.U_SINGLE);
        hlink_font.setColor(IndexedColors.BLUE.getIndex());
        hlink_style.setFont(hlink_font);
        //hlink_style.setWrapText(true);

        XSSFHyperlink link = createHelper.createHyperlink(HyperlinkType.FILE);
        link.setAddress(url);
        cell.setHyperlink(link);
        cell.setCellStyle(hlink_style);
          
        fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path);
        workbook.write(fileOut);

        fileOut.close();    

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    
    
    
    // returns true if sheet is created successfully else false
    public boolean addSheet(String  sheetname){     
        
        FileOutputStream fileOut;
        try {
             workbook.createSheet(sheetname);   
             fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path);
             workbook.write(fileOut);
             fileOut.close();           
        } catch (Exception e) {         
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    
    // returns true if sheet is removed successfully else false if sheet does not exist
    public boolean removeSheet(String sheetName){       
        int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName);
        if(index==-1)
            return false;
        
        FileOutputStream fileOut;
        try {
            workbook.removeSheetAt(index);
            fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path);
            workbook.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();            
        } catch (Exception e) {         
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    // returns true if column is created successfully
    public boolean addColumn(String sheetName,String colName){
        
        
        try{                
            fis = new FileInputStream(path); 
            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
            int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName);
            if(index==-1)
                return false;
            
        XSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
        style.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.HSSFColorPredefined.GREY_40_PERCENT.getIndex());
        style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        
        sheet=workbook.getSheetAt(index);
        
        row = sheet.getRow(0);
        if (row == null)
            row = sheet.createRow(0);
        
        
        if(row.getLastCellNum() == -1)
            cell = row.createCell(0);
        else
            cell = row.createCell(row.getLastCellNum());
            
            cell.setCellValue(colName);
            cell.setCellStyle(style);
            
            fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path);
            workbook.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();            

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        
        return true;
        
        
    }
    
    
    
    // removes a column and all the contents
    public boolean removeColumn(String sheetName, int colNum) {
        try{
        if(!isSheetExist(sheetName))
            return false;
        fis = new FileInputStream(path); 
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        sheet=workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
        XSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
        style.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.HSSFColorPredefined.GREY_40_PERCENT.getIndex());
        XSSFCreationHelper createHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
        style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.NO_FILL);
        
        
    
        for(int i =0;i<getRowCount(sheetName);i++){
            row=sheet.getRow(i);    
            if(row!=null){
                cell=row.getCell(colNum);
                if(cell!=null){
                    cell.setCellStyle(style);
                    row.removeCell(cell);
                }
            }
        }
        fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path);
        workbook.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
        
    }
    
    
  // find whether sheets exists 
    public boolean isSheetExist(String sheetName){
        int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName);
        if(index==-1){
            index=workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName.toUpperCase());
                if(index==-1)
                    return false;
                else
                    return true;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }
    
    
    // returns number of columns in a sheet 
    public int getColumnCount(String sheetName){
        // check if sheet exists
        if(!isSheetExist(sheetName))
         return -1;
        
        sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
        row = sheet.getRow(0);
        
        if(row==null)
            return -1;
        
        return row.getLastCellNum();
        
        
        
    }
    
    
    //String sheetName, String testCaseName,String keyword ,String URL,String message
    public boolean addHyperLink(String sheetName,String screenShotColName,String testCaseName,int index,String url,String message){
        
        
        url=url.replace('\\', '/');
        if(!isSheetExist(sheetName))
             return false;
        
        sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
        
        for(int i=2;i<=getRowCount(sheetName);i++){
            if(getCellData(sheetName, 0, i).equalsIgnoreCase(testCaseName)){
                
                setCellData(sheetName, screenShotColName, i+index, message,url);
                break;
            }
        }


        return true; 
    }
    public int getCellRowNum(String sheetName,String colName,String cellValue){
        
        for(int i=2;i<=getRowCount(sheetName);i++){
            if(getCellData(sheetName,colName , i).equalsIgnoreCase(cellValue)){
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
        
    }
        
    
    // to run this on stand alone
    public static void main(String arg[]) throws IOException{
        
        
        ExcelReader datatable = null;
        

             datatable = new ExcelReader("C:\\CM3.0\\app\\test\\Framework\\AutomationBvt\\src\\config\\xlfiles\\Controller.xlsx");
                for(int col=0 ;col< datatable.getColumnCount("TC5"); col++){
                    System.out.println(datatable.getCellData("TC5", col, 1));
                }
    }
    
}
```

[image]

I dont know why this error occurs. I have added all the required dependencies. the excel reader is from a separe course and that doesn't show any error. only my code - which uses this class, is showing this error.

Comment: check to be sure you've only got one version of POI added as a dependency... (just a guess... maybe include your POM.XML file in your post...)

Comment: Thank you @pcalkins that helped. I changed all my POI version to 3.1.0 and resolved this issue.

Comment: there is no POI version with the number 3.1.0 - there is an XMLBeans release with version 3.1.0

Comment: sorry xmlbeans to 3.1.0 and poi to 4.1.2.